# Play Anorm insert a scala List into a postgres text array column

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4, anorm

I'm trying to insert a List[String] into a postgresql column of type text[]. I believe when you attempt to insert any List, Anorm inserts each member of the List in its own column. I'm pretty sure this is the case because I get back the exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
```

What I want to do is insert the entire List as a text[]. My current code:

```
def insertList(listName: String, subLists: List[String]): Long = {
DB.withConnection{implicit c =>
SQL(
  """
    INSERT INTO mailinglists(name, sublists) VALUES({listName}, {subLists})
  """)
  .on('listName -> listName, 'subLists -> subLists)
  .executeInsert(scalar[Long] single)
}
}
```

I tried to go down this path:

```
ConnectionPool.borrow().createArrayOf("text", subLists.toArray)
```

But I get the error:

```
type mismatch;
found   : (Symbol, java.sql.Array)
required: anorm.NamedParameter
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that ended up working for this issue was:

```
def insertList(listName: String, subLists: List[String]): Long = {
DB.withConnection{implicit c =>
  SQL"INSERT INTO mailinglists(name, sublists) VALUES($listName, ARRAY[$subLists])"
  .executeInsert(scalar[Long] single)
}
}
```

What changed from the original post was the use of Anorm string interpolation SQL"..." and the addition of `ARRAY[...]` around the multi-value parameter. I'm not exactly sure why this worked as the postgres exceptions were very mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

The values passed as parameters to Anorm are not supposed to be raw JDBC values. You should not pass `java.sql.*` values; You can have a look at the [parameter mappings](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm#Parameters).

Then you are passing parameter names as `Symbol`, which has been deprecated in Anorm 2.3 and is not longer supported since 2.4. Names must be passed as `String`.

The SQL array can be passed as `Array[T]`, with `T` supported as parameter type.

You can also have a look at documentation about the [multi-value parameters](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm#Multi-value-support).

Comment: So i transformed the List using .toArray which resolved, but now I'm getting " org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to find server array type for provided name VARCHAR". The column its being inserted into is a text[].

Comment: Is anorm passing some typecast "VARCHAR" when it should be passing "varchar" ?

Comment: Here you can see anorm using "VARCHAR" as the "sqlType" and jdbcType https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/ce5e676ff0317eb3005156bd5717c768b9f8dc40/core/src/main/scala/anorm/ParameterMetaData.scala

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't matter the case. Your issue is elsewhere. You can try multi-value `SQL"INSERT INTO mailinglists(name, sublists) VALUES($listName, ARRAY[$subLists])"`

Comment: So the key to getting passed the VARCHAR exception was switching my SQL to string interpolation. However, now I'm hitting another mysterious psql exception. If i run it with the code you suggested, `INSERT INTO mailinglists(name, sublists) VALUES($listName, ARRAY[$array])` I get  ` org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" Position: 86` If i execute it without ARRAY[...] I get: ` org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" Position: 62` Neither SQL statement contains the problematic char in the exception

Comment: Be sure to use the `SQL"..."` interpolation and to use as `Seq` for the multi-value parameter (prepared inside the `ARRAY[]`).