# Play Anorm causing PSQLException "Unable to find server array type for provided name VARCHAR"

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm

I'm trying to insert a List[String] in a postgres text[] (text array) column using the following code:

```
  def insertList(listName: String, subLists: List[String]): Long = {
    DB.withConnection{implicit c =>
      SQL(
         """
           INSERT INTO mailinglists(name, sublists) VALUES({listName}, {subLists})
         """)
           .on('listName -> listName, 'subLists -> subLists.toArray)
           .executeInsert(scalar[Long] single)
        }
   }
```

This is throwing the runtime exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to find server array type for provided name VARCHAR
```

When I search on this exception, most solutions tell the poster to make their typecast "VARCHAR" lowercase [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931654/how-create-a-sql-array-from-a-java-list)

Except when using anorm, the code that is doing this is hidden, something like:

```
ConnectionPool.borrow().createArrayOf("VARCHAR", array));
```

Additionally, I found this in [Anorm's ParameterMetaData code](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/ce5e676ff0317eb3005156bd5717c768b9f8dc40/core/src/main/scala/anorm/ParameterMetaData.scala)

```
implicit object StringParameterMetaData extends ParameterMetaData[String] {
   val sqlType = "VARCHAR"
   val jdbcType = Types.VARCHAR
  }
```

Not sure if it's the cause. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to create a string from this list? how do you expect the list to be saved in postgres? comma separated? space separated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Anorm insert a scala List into a postgres text array column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444343/play-anorm-insert-a-scala-list-into-a-postgres-text-array-column)